# Is there a grid compatible with Polymer 2?

Tags: polymer, web-component

It would be nice if https://www.webcomponents.org/ allowed you to limit your search to elements compatible with version 2 of Polymer.

I tried vaadin-grid but it's not compatible with Polymer 2.

Does anybody know of a grid that works with Polymer 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some versions, you may select the version right side : https://www.webcomponents.org/element/vaadin/vaadin-grid

Comment: I installed 3.0.0-alpha2 and it's working fine. Version 2 is supposed to work, but I can't get it to, and I'm not the only one: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/908

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vaadin-grid. To use vaadin-grid in Polymer 2.x download vaadin-grid v3.0.0-alpha2. You can download it using following command:
bower install --save vaadin/vaadin-grid@v3.0.0-alpha2

Vaadin-grid version 2.x doesn't support Polymer 2.x.
[Reference](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/issues/885)

Answer (score 0):

We have just used Wijmo in our Polymer application.  I know it isn't a "Polymer" component but it seems to work just fine for us.